# Netbeans autocompletion selection key

Tags: java, netbeans, ide

After pressing ctrl-space, netbeans pops up a menu for possible completions:

[image]

I can use the up and down keys to select among them, but it's not efficient, as you have to move your hand quite far away. Any way to customize this?

Comment: You can simple write `serr` and press tab key, it will autocomplete `System.err.println("")`, or `sout` and it will autocomplete `System.out.println("")`.

Comment: Yeah, but that's not a general solution.